# Estimating P value of average estimate

Tags: statistical-significance, mean, p-value

I have five estimates indicating accuracy improvement applying a specific algorithm. Suppose the accuracy gains are 3.48, 5.82, 5.41, -2.272, -10.08. The negative values indicate the algorithm resulted in accuracy loss.

The average accuracy gain for five scenarios would be 0.47. Is there any way to say if the accuracy gain is significant? Meaning can I do a test to get a p value?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need any statistical test. You have five values. Three are positive; two are negative. There are fewer negative tests, but their absolute value (on average) is bigger. About half the time, the accuracy goes up; the other half, it goes down. What more is there to say? (As is often the case, the word "significant" obscures clear thinking.)

Comment: Your answer is predicated on the implicit assumption that all five values should be equally weighted in one's consideration. There could be plenty more to say, given details of those estimates.  For instance, the negative estimates could be highly uncertain compared to the positive estimates, which--if sufficiently precise and independent--could establish the plausibility of a positive gain.

Comment: @whuber. Sure, if there were more information, there would be more to say and analyses to do!

Comment: These estimates came from five scenarios actually. I simulated data to build five scenarios and got the result. My main point was the algorithm can result in both better and worse result. 

However, my professor asked if I can say "overall, the gain was significant"- that's what confused me

Comment: @MSilvy The question "is it significant' is too vague. What are you comparing to what? What assumptions are you willing to make (sampling from Gaussian distribution?)? What is a "scenario"? Are there replicate values? Or just five measurements? What do you want to compare them to?  Without a fully specified question, no one will be able to help you find the right path to find the answer.

Comment: Please let me rephrase the question

This question already has an answer here:
Estimating P value of average estimate (1 answer)
Your post has been associated with a similar question. If this question doesn’t resolve your question, ask a new one.

Closed 3 days ago.

(Private feedback for you)

I have analyzed accuracy gain for applying an algorithm. For six different parameters, six estimates (both gain and loss) were obtained.

I am wondering how can I do a strong statistical test to say the average estimate over the six cases is significant. Is a chi-sq test strong enough?